# How to find the total count of duplicate name

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a table

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tblTeams](
[Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[TeamId] [varchar](5) NOT NULL,
[TeamName] [varchar](100) NOT NULL,
[PlayerName] [varchar](100) NOT NULL,
[PlayerNickName] [varchar](100) NULL,
[Status] [int] NULL
```

Now I have written a Stored Procedure:

```
Alter Proc [dbo].[SpGetDuplicateName]
    @PlayerName varchar(200)
AS
Begin
(
    Select PlayerName,TeamName,TeamId 
    from tblTeams where PlayerName like @PlayerName 
)
END
```

Now I want to return the Count of how many times a name has been replicated

Help required

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please show some sample input and expected output

Answer (score 3):

Small twist to Ullas query...  The HAVING will return only dupes

```
SELECT PlayerName, COUNT(PlayerName) AS [Count]
FROM tblTeams
WHERE PlayerName LIKE '%word_to_search%'
GROUP BY PlayerName;
HAVING COUNT(*)>1
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `COUNT` with `GROUP BY`.

**Query**

```
SELECT PlayerName, COUNT(PlayerName) AS [Count]
FROM tblTeams
WHERE PlayerName LIKE '%word_to_search%'
GROUP BY PlayerName;
```

Comment: Very Helpful.@Ullas